# How do I know if a LCD is compatible with my Laptop?

Tags: lcd, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Precision M65 and I need to change de LCD. ¿Where do I find if certain LCD of another laptop is compatible? I see some "compatible" LCDs in Internet but I am not really sure.

Comment: What do you mean by a "compatible LCD"? Are you trying to find an external monitor to use with your laptop or do you need to replace the built-in screen of the laptop itself?

Comment: Hi, i am replacing the laptop's screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, bear in mind that replacing your own LCD panel means taking apart some of your laptop and has the potential to break things if you don't have the right tools and a degree of repair experience (I used to work for a systems house that repaired laptops and have replaced many LCD panels)

You may need to identify the current panel's manufacturer and model code by looking at the stickers on it, which means opening up the casing (see above warning) but I have found that many of the LCD panel sellers on ebay (UK) are very helpful and I have telephoned several in the past for compatibility advice.