# How can I tell if a replacement display is compatible with my laptop?

Tags: display, led

I have an Acer Aspire 4810TZ from 2010 which I truly love - it's a 3 year old notebook that still carries on for about 5 to 6h straight off the battery. I've also invested in it with an SSD and extra RAM and it's fine for my use right now. I'd really rather not just dump it.

Now... its screen is dead and I'm looking for replacement parts, but it turns out to be a kind of expensive display - AUO B140XW02 14" LED. US$ 125 was the cheapest I found here (Rio de Janeiro, Brazil). The official dealer sells them for US$ 175.

I'm aware of [How do I know if a LCD is compatible with my Laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/201783/how-do-i-know-if-a-lcd-is-compatible-with-my-laptop) and [Can I replace a laptop screen with one of a different resolution?](https://superuser.com/questions/220271/can-i-replace-a-laptop-screen-with-one-of-a-different-resolution) but the answers don't really help me in this case. Also [Replacing an LCD screen in a laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/118045/replacing-an-lcd-screen-in-a-laptop) gives me a hint but I'm completely dumb at hardware so this is why i'm asking:

**Is it possible to buy an LCD or a lower grade LED screen with the same connectors? What characteristics should I look for to find out if a certain display is compatible?**

Comment: You could also get a used external monitor for cheap and use the laptop as a spare desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all get a monitor of the same type. Don't try to replace a LED with an LCD or vice versa. It adds a whole level of complexity as to compatibility.

All manufacturers create a document for servicing laptops. There you will find a list of all part numbers. It is important that you find the document that covers your exact model. After that, just filter through the parts list.

Here is a [link to the manual](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Acer%20Computers/Aspire-4810TZ/Manual/114337). Check out page 102 for more information.